# Progress for downloading large CSV files from Internet using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-requests

I am reading McKinney's Data Analysis book, and he has shared 150MB file. Although this topic has been discussed extensively at [Progress Bar while download file over http with Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573483/progress-bar-while-download-file-over-http-with-requests?answertab=votes#tab-top), I am finding that the code in accepted answer is throwing an error. I am a beginner, so I am unable to resolve this.

I want to download the following file:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/fec/P00000001-ALL.csv
```

Here's the code without progress bar:

```
DATA_PATH='./Data'
filename = "P00000001-ALL.csv"
url_without_filename = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/fec"

url_with_filename = url_without_filename + "/" + filename
local_filename = DATA_PATH + '/' + filename

#Write the file on local disk
r = requests.get(url_with_filename)  #without streaming
with open(local_filename, 'w', encoding=r.encoding) as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

This works well, but because there is no progress bar, I wonder what's going on.

Here's the code adapted from [Progress Bar while download file over http with Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573483/progress-bar-while-download-file-over-http-with-requests?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [How to download large file in python with requests.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
#Option 2:
#Write the file on local disk
r = requests.get(url_with_filename, stream=True)  # added stream parameter
total_size = int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0))

with open(local_filename, 'w', encoding=r.encoding) as f:
    #f.write(r.text)
    for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(1024), total=total_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
```

There are **two problems** with the second option (i.e. with streaming and `tqdm` package):

a) The file size isn't calculated correctly. The actual size is 157MB, but the `total_size` turns out to be 25MB.

b) Even bigger problem than a) is that I get the following error:

```
 0%|          | 0.00/24.6M [00:00<?, ?B/s] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3265, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "<ipython-input-31-abbe9270092b>", line 6, in <module>
    f.write(data) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

As a beginner, I am unsure how to solve these two issues. I spent a lot of time going through git page of `tqdm`, but I couldn't follow it. I'd appreciate any help.

---

I am assuming that the readers know that we need to import `requests` and `tqdm`. So, I haven't included the code for importing these basic packages.

---

> Here's the code for those who are curious:

```
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    r = requests.get(url_with_filename, stream=True)  # added stream parameter
    # total_size = int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    local_filename = DATA_PATH + '/' + filename
    total_size = len(r.content)
    downloaded = 0
    # chunk_size = max(1024*1024,int(total_size/1000))
    chunk_size = 1024
    #for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size),total=total_size,unit='KB',unit_scale=True):
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        downloaded += len(chunk)
        a=f.write(chunk)
        done = int(50 * downloaded/ total_size)
        sys.stdout.write("\r[%s%s]" % ('=' * done, ' ' * (50 - done)))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Find a way to get the true size of the file and the progress bar is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'wb', encoding=r.encoding) as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

This should fix your writing problem. Write `r.content` not `r.text`
Since `type(r.content)` is `<class 'bytes'>` which is what you need to write in the file

Answer (score 1):

As the error says :

> write() argument must be str, not bytes

so just convert *chunk* to *string* :

```
f.write(str(chunk))
```

Note: Instead I would suggest to write to a *.bin* file and then convert it to *.csv*

Answer (score 0):

Try writing with `wb` instead of just `w`.

```
with open( local_filename, 'wb', encoding= r.encoding ) as f:
    f.write( r.text )
```

Comment: I just checked. Both issues persist. Also, the issue isn't about plainly downloading the file, but about using progress bar and calculating the size correctly.