# tqdm not showing progress bar with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, request, tqdm

Why doesn't `tqdm` work here when combined with `requests`? When I run the script below, all I get is a blinking cursor, no progress bar. Thank you.

```
import requests, re
from tqdm import tqdm

link = "https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status&matchType=prefix&filter=statuscode:200"
flamingo = []

y = requests.get(link).text
urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', y)

for url in tqdm(urls):
    flamingo.append(f"{url}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works fine if you just add a `limit` argument to your URL.

```
link = "https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status&matchType=prefix&filter=statuscode:200&limit=10"
```

The list of tweets you get without limit is very, very long. I assume that your code doesn't reach your loop before timing out. (This at least was the case when I tested your script)

Comment: Pete, thanks! Appreciate your help :) You're correct: the list of tweets is really long. But ultimately, it's a file. Just like how Firefox shows me a progress bar for downloading it, I think `requests` combined with `tqdm` should do the same. I think it's a bug.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with tqdm and requests combination. It just takes long to get this urls list. The donwload is finished in the line wäre you put that file into y

Comment: Hi Simon. Do you think `tqdm` can be used to track the time it takes for Python to get the URLs list? Or is that not possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573483/progress-bar-while-download-file-over-http-with-requests