Get subprocess output in Python without overwriting progress bar
I'm trying to download a file in Python with wget2. It repeatedly prints the output progress bar, which as a standalone process is ok, since it returns to line beginning with \r. However, I don't know how to achieve this in Python. I need output in real time, as the file is being downloaded.
Code:
url = "https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chembl/ChEMBLdb/releases/chembl_35/chembl_35.sdf.gz"
cmd = [
    "wget2",
    url,
    f"--max-threads=5",
    "-N",  # re-download only updated files
    # set nice outputs
    "--no-verbose",
    "--force-progress",
]
subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)

Outputs:
7[Files: 0  Bytes: 0  []
7[https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk]87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]   46.57K    --.-KB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]  202.82K    1.22MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]  359.07K    1.22MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]  491.88K    1.15MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]  679.38K    1.23MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]  859.07K    1.26MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]  999.69K    1.23MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]    1.15M    1.27MB/s87Just got 1351689 of 805068706 bytes (https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chembl/ChEMBLdb/releases/chembl_35/chembl_35.sdf.gz)
87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]    1.28M    1.25MB/s87chembl_35.sdf.gz       0% [>                    ]    1.28M    1.25MB/s87[Files: 0  Bytes: 0  []8Traceback (most recent call last):

I guess that I have to do something with Popen, but everything that I've tried just printed empty lines.

If you want the output to go to stdout and stderr, you don't need to pass the stdout/stderr arguments; it goes there by default. So you can simplify to just subprocess.run(cmd, check=True). That aside, what are you trying to do? Do the same thing that wget2 is doing in Python? Or just do what you're doing and have it display as expected? It should work the same either way if run in the same terminal, what terminal are you using for each tool? The one that ships with most IDEs will not support \r.

Why are you shelling out? Do something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/37573483/3001761

@ShadowRanger I want to just run the same thing in Python, and have real-time display. Basically, I just want Python as a glue instead of Bash script, since I have to use it later for processing anyway. I am using regular terminal, as well as PyCharm's run, with the same result.

If you run the script from an ordinary terminal window, I would expect the wget2 output to be the same as if you'd run the wget2 command from that same terminal. When displaying the progress bar, it simply checks whether stdout is a terminal or not, it doesn't care whether the parent process is python or a shell.

There's nothing you need to or can do to affect how wget2 interacts with the terminal if you're not intercepting the output.
